# Migrations doesn't starts for dockerized Django project

Tags: django, bash, docker

I've created e simple `hello world` project with Django and Docker. At the end of `Dockerfile` there is the command below:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/web/entrypoint.sh"]
```

that activate this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo " ---> DB Connection Parameters: \
            DB name: $DB_NAME \
            DB host: $DB_HOST \
            DB port: $DB_PORT"

poetry run python3 website/manage.py migrate --noinput

poetry run python3 website/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

poetry run python3 website/manage.py createsuperuser --noinput

echo " ---> Django Project Port: $PROJECT_PORT"

poetry run python3 website/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:"$PROJECT_PORT"

exec "$@"
```

The project starts but the migration isn't run and I'm forced to log inside the container and use `python3 manage.py migrate` to start the migration.

Why the migration command doesn't run and `collectstatic` runs automatically?

Below the docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    container_name: dev_db
    image: postgis/postgis
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  website:
    image: maxdragonheart/${PROJECT_NAME}
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      PROJECT_NAME: ${PROJECT_NAME}
      PROJECT_PORT: ${PROJECT_PORT}
      SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
      DB_ENGINE: ${DB_ENGINE}
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DEBUG: ${DEBUG}
      ALLOWED_HOSTS: ${ALLOWED_HOSTS}
    container_name: dev_website
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${PROJECT_PORT}:${PROJECT_PORT}
    volumes:
      - website-static-folder:/app/web/static-folder
      - website-media-folder:/app/web/media-folder
      - logs:/app/logs
    depends_on:
      - db


volumes:
  db-data:
  website-static-folder:
  website-media-folder:
  logs:
```

Comment: If you look at `docker-compose logs website`, do you see the other diagnostics from this script?  Is there anything else in the Dockerfile that might be relevant to the question?  What you show seems like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker runs `manage.py collectstatic --noinput` automatically, you don't have to run command for it. For custom commands, you can try adding this:

```
website:
  ...
  command: bash -c "python3 website/manage.py migrate --noinput &&
                    python3 website/manage.py createsuperuser --noinput &&
                    python3 website/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:[YOUR PORT]"
  ...
```

to your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: ...but all of those commands are already in the entrypoint script, and will run before the image's `CMD` (the final `exec "$@"` line).  Why do you need a complex `command:` override like this?